# Testing Head inside a Module

Tags: programming, head

I hava a `Module` in which a want to give a single String or a List as a parameter and I want to change a single String to a List containing this String. So I did the following:

```
ClearAll[test];
test[in_] := Module[{},
  If[Head[in] == String, {in}, in]
  ]
```

Now `test["a"]` works fine, but `test[{"a","b"}]` not, it returns the `If` statement.

```
If[List == String, {{"a", "b"}}, {"a", "b"}]
```

Can anyone give me a hint why this is so and.. how to fix it?

Comment: Change `==` to `===`.

Comment: @corey979: Thanks! This works. Any explanation why the `==`returns the If-Statement?

Comment: Check out the tutorial for [`Conditionals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Conditionals.html): The equation `List == String` is seen as **indeterminate**; in that case the `If[...]` statement is returned unevaluated, as the equation will not evaluate to either `True` or `False`.

Comment: @mgamer Because `==` is for math, not for comparing expressions.  You need to be able to write equations like `x == y` and pass them to `Solve`.  Sadly, Wolfram themselves are guilty of misusing `==` many times in the documentation ... so it's not a surprise if you were confused.

Comment: It's remarkable that such an example is not in the documentation for either `If` or `Equal`.  It seems a common mistake.  I've made it several times, even after learning the difference (e.g. `If[OptionValue["Foo"] == Automatic,...]`).

Comment: @MichaelE2: me, too ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Mathematica evaluator is designed to discriminate on the heads of arguments on request, and can do it faster than an `If` coded inside an unnecessary `Module`. Write it this way.

```
test[in_String] := {in}
test[in___] := in
```

Then

```
test /@ test /@ {42, "foo", Sin, 42 + "foo", <|"foo" -> 42|>}
```

> `{42, {"foo"}, Sin, 42 + "foo", <|"foo" -> 42|>}`

Comment: Thank you for this answer, the module is, in this case, not unnecessary, I only stripped everything else off, to make a MWE, nevertheless I´mn going to check whether your proposal is the faster implementation. :-)